# ERROR: (gcloud.beta.filestore.instances.create) PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission 'file.instances.create' denied on 'projects/----`

Tags: gcloud, google-iam, google-cloud-filestore

I'm running this command to create a google cloud filestore

```
gcloud beta filestore instances create devopscube-nfs-server     --zone=us-central1-c     --tier=STANDARD     --file-share=name="devopscubefileserver",capacity=1TB     --network=name="default",reserved-ip-range="10.0.0.0/29"
```

and i get this error : -

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.filestore.instances.create) PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission 'file.instances.create' denied on 'projects/lynkit-blockchain-256614/locations/us-central1-c/instances/devopscube-nfs-server'
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Gcloud console in web. In the sidebar find IAM & Admin . Then find your email address and click on edit icon. Then add two roles that are :-

`Cloud Filestore Editor` and Cloud `Filestore Viewer` and you're done.